# systemd script works but not using curl

Tags: linux, curl, systemd

I am struggling with migrating an init script to systemd, on Debian Jessie.

The goal is to access an URL after booting and before shutdown. The service file looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=some_name
After=syslog.target network-online.target 
Wants=network-online.target 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/xyz/scripts/register.bash
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/xyz/scripts/deregister.bash
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The register script (URLs replaced by xyz, echos for debugging):

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$(hostname -I)
IP=${IP/ /}

echo  "-- register $(date) IP=$IP"  >>/home/xyz/register.txt
echo  "   $(who -r) ID=$(id) HOST=$(host x.y.z)" >>/home/xyz/register.txt

/usr/bin/curl --max-time 30 "http://x.y.z/some_script" -s -o /dev/null 

echo "   exit code $?" >>/home/xyz/register.txt

echo "-- reg done $(date)" >>/home/xyz/register.txt

exit 0
```

Triggering the scripts from the command line works as expected, also as root. In particular, curl accesses the URL as it should.

Also, the script is started upon booting and shutdown and leads the corresponding traces in register.txt. So far so good.

What does not work, however, is that curl exits with code 28 (timeout) when started via systemd. This also happens when I trigger it with "systemd start " from a fully booted system with network up and running. So the unavailability of the network seems not to be the reason for the timeout.

Why does curl timeout under these conditions, and what do I need to change to get the service running as intended?

Thanks for your help

Comment: this sort of issue is better discussed at the stackexchange-related site http://unix.stackexchange.com ... That said, glad you solved your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

This all happens on a virtual server, and http access is now via a proxy which had not been there before when I used the init script.

Setting the proxy variable in the script called by systemd solved the problem...